# Is it correct to write "someone wants to focus on their study"?

Tags: word-choice

Here is the situation.

My colleague, T1000 recently quit his job as a shop assistant.
He is cool but nice. He was doing a part-time degree in a university.
He told us that his school assignment had become harder and heavier, so he wanted to quit the job.

Now, in my diary, I am writing this:

> T1000 has quit the job so that he can **focus on** his school work and thesis.

I am not sure whether it is correct to write "someone wants to *focus on their something*"?

If it is not correct, can you suggest some other way of saying it?

Comment: *'he can focus on his studies'* looks *absolutely* fine to me. Why do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: "Focus" is fine.  Another way of saying the same is "concentrate".

Comment: Hi, Victor Bazarov. Do you mean "someone concentrates on something."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Focus* can take an object, answering the question *who or what is being focused?*.  The typical preposition used with *focus* is *on*:

> I focused the gun sight on the target.

If you don't specify an object, the "default" object is yourself.

> I focused [myself] on my homework.

but if you leave out the *on* it sounds like what comes after is the object of the verb *focus*

> I focused my homework { on ... what? }